# PHP array insert into mysql using some operations

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I have MySQL table containing as  `serials(start,end,quantity,status)` .

start-start serial,end-end serial, quantity- difference between start and end, and status is 'R' or 'P'.
Suppose I have supplied user 1-1000 R serials, user then enter multiple entries between 1-1000.

I am getting array of serials(sorted) from user as

```
$arr=array(
array(
'start'=>201,
'end'=>300,
'quantity'=>100),

array(
'start'=>401,
'end'=>600,
'quantity'=>200),

array(
'start'=>701,
'end'=>850,
'quantity'=>150)
)
```

I want the to insert records in table as

(start,end,quantity,status)

1. (1,200,200,R)
2. (201,300,100,P)
3. (301,400,100,R)
4. (401,600,200,P)
5. (601,700,100,R)
6. (701,850,150,P)
7. (851,1000,150,R)

What I have tried will only insert 1st and last record  of R and all P records but not in between records of R

```
$this->db->where("md5(serial_id)",$serial_id);
        $dd2=$this->db->get("serial")->row_array();
    $arr=array(
                "start"=>$dd['start_serial_no'],
                "end"=>$ins_arr[0]['start_serial_no']-1,
                'quantity'=>$ins_arr[0]['start_serial_no']-$dd['start_serial_no'],
                'status'=>'R',  

                );
            $this->db->insert('serial',$arr);
    for($i=0;$i<count($ins_arr);$i++)
    {
        $arr=array(
                "start_serial_no"=>$dd['start_serial_no'],
                "end_serial_no"=>$ins_arr[0]['start_serial_no']-1,
                'quantity'=>$ins_arr[0]['start_serial_no']-$dd['start_serial_no'],
                'status'=>'P',  
                );
            $this->db->insert('serial',$arr);

    }
    $arr=array(
                "start_serial_no"=>$ins_arr[$i-1]['start_serial_no'],
                "end_serial_no"=>$dd['end_serial_no'],
                'quantity'=>$ins_arr[$i-1]['start_serial_no']-$dd['start_serial_no'],
                'status'=>'R',  
                );
            $this->db->insert('serial',$arr);
```

Comment: Why do you need the quantity specified, where it seems to me that it's a simple subtraction between end and start? (end -start -1 to be precise)? At the moment your table is not normalized, and unless a very edge case, that's almost always A Bad Thing.

Comment: point noted, will work on that but can you please consider main quenstion

Comment: I can't because I'm not fluent with codeigniter, sorry. But I can help with DB theory, hence the comment and not an answer :) Good luck with your question anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to modify it as follows.

```
$this->db->where("md5(serial_id)",$serial_id);
    $dd2=$this->db->get("serial")->row_array();
$arr=array(
            "start"=>$dd['start_serial_no'],
            "end"=>$ins_arr[0]['start_serial_no']-1,
            'quantity'=>$ins_arr[0] ['start_serial_no']-$dd['start_serial_no'],
            'status'=>'R',  

            );
        $this->db->insert('serial',$arr);
for($i=0;$i<count($ins_arr);$i++)
{
    $p_arr=array(
            "start_serial_no"=>$dd['start_serial_no'],
            "end_serial_no"=>$ins_arr[0]['start_serial_no']-1,
            'quantity'=>$ins_arr[0]['start_serial_no']-$dd['start_serial_no'],
            'status'=>'P',  
            );
        $this->db->insert('serial',$p_arr);

      $r_arr=array(
            "start_serial_no"=>$p_arr['start_serial_no'] + $p_arr['quantity'] ,
            "end_serial_no"=>$p_arr['start_serial_no'] + $p_arr['quantity'] + 100,
            'quantity'=> 100,
            'status'=>'R',  
            );
        $this->db->insert('serial',$r_arr);



}
$arr=array(
            "start_serial_no"=>$ins_arr[$i-1]['start_serial_no'],
            "end_serial_no"=>$dd['end_serial_no'],
            'quantity'=>$ins_arr[$i-1]['start_serial_no']-$dd['start_serial_no'],
            'status'=>'R',  
            );
        $this->db->insert('serial',$arr);
```

Comment: okay, its looks good, but why did you take 100 constant quantity.

Comment: I just added required logic to add R values, you can modify it as you required.

Comment: no but i want that logic to add R values, since start and end no will vary so the difference between them(i.e.quantity)

Answer (score 0):

$this->db->insert_batch();

batch  insert can be used to insert array that you listed in your question.you can find tutorial here.

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: you didn't understand question,i know insert_batch(), i want those values to insert(see 1 to 7 records).

Answer (score 0):

Tough I am accepting shanusingh answer.I did some modifications to that. Answering for anybody else have same issue

```
    $this->db->where("md5(serial_id)",$serial_id);
    $dd=$this->db->get("serial")->row_array();
    $arr=array(
                "start_serial_no"=>$dd['start_serial_no'],
                "end_serial_no"=>$ins_arr[0]['start_serial_no']-1,
                'quantity'=>$ins_arr[0]['start_serial_no']-$dd['start_serial_no'],
                'status'=>'R',  
                );
            $this->db->insert('serial',$arr);

    for($i=0;$i<count($ins_arr);$i++)
    {
        $p_arr=array(
                "start_serial_no"=>$ins_arr[$i]['start_serial_no'],
                "end_serial_no"=>$ins_arr[$i]['end_serial_no'],
                'quantity'=>$ins_arr[$i]['end_serial_no']-$ins_arr[$i]['start_serial_no']+1,
                'status'=>'P',  
                );
            $this->db->insert('serial',$p_arr);

        if($i!=count($ins_arr)-1)   
        {
             $r_arr=array(
            "start_serial_no"=>$p_arr['end_serial_no']+1,
            "end_serial_no"=>$ins_arr[$i+1]['start_serial_no']-1,
            'quantity'=> $ins_arr[$i+1]['start_serial_no']-$p_arr['end_serial_no']-1,
            'status'=>'R',  
            );

            $this->db->insert('serial',$r_arr);
        }
    }
    $arr=array(
            "start_serial_no"=>$ins_arr[$i-1]['end_serial_no'],
            "end_serial_no"=>$dd['end_serial_no'],
            'quantity'=>$dd['end_serial_no']-$ins_arr[$i-1]['end_serial_no']+1,
            'status'=>'R',  
            );
            $this->db->insert('serial',$arr);
```